# Can a sport team "clinch" a championship in the last regular season game?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, language-change

This question gets into the subtle shades of meaning of the word *clinch*, in the context of sporting teams securing spots in the playoffs.

My past experience hearing this term on television, or reading in the newspaper, carries the connotation of "regardless of the outcome of (this or other teams') remaining games."  The [free dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/clinch) seems to agree.

However, recent coverage (question written during the last week of the 2014 NFL season) has described several teams having the opportunity to "clinch" a wild-card spot with a win on Sunday, if some other team also loses, or similar scenarios, always using the word *clinch*.  At this point, I would say that the team can earn, win, receive, capture, or any of a dozen other terms, but the time to be able to clinch has passed.

So, is my perception of the meaning of *clinch* flawed?  Or, is there clear evidence that the meaning is changing as a result of popular usage (i.e. by sports tele-casters and writers)?

Comment: Just for clarity: do you mean that "clinch" should mean "guarantee, even though there are games remaining," but after the final week there will be no remaining (regular season) games, so we might say "secure" but not "clinch"?

Comment: @Rusty Tuba:  Yes, that is what I am asking.

Comment: I see what you mean. It hadn't occurred to me before, and I would guess that they are using "clinch" as a synonym of "secure" (a word which does not necessarily imply that there remain meaningless regular season games).

Comment: At what point has the "time to be able to clinch passed"? And what's wrong with, _"The Chiefs can clinch with a win plus a Ravens loss and a Texans loss or tie"_ – do you not like the word "clinch" because the Chiefs "need help"? I think the usage is fine, and your perception is flawed. (In that context, it simply means, "If the Chiefs win, the Ravens lose, and the Texans tie, then the Chiefs have clinched a berth – no matter what else happens on Sunday.")

Comment: In the context of your question, the definition your link points to, namely "To secure (a divisional championship, for instance) before the end of regular season play by having an insurmountable lead", is the only sense I am familiar with. An 'opportunity to clinch' is no opportunity at all if securing a spot still depends on the outcome of some other sports match.

Comment: the old "conditional clinch"

Comment: For me, the difference is "there will be games in the future, but those games will not influence this outcome" versus "there are no more future games."  In the first case, clinch is clearly appropriate; in the second, I have doubts.

Comment: @cobaltduck - In the second case, you can simply change the tense: _The Ravens have clinched a playoff spot_. Also, even though 16 games get played this Sunday, ten of them will be over relatively early in the day, but there will still be six more yet to play. It's those other six games that might justify the use of the word _clinch_, even in the final week of the season.

Comment: [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/clinch?searchDictCode=all) doesn't include this nuance in its definition. So while the word is often used when the team secures a win early in the season, it's not necessary to use the term.

Comment: I think you may hear it used more when the team secures the win early just because it's more newsworthy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the entry for the transitive verb *clinch* in *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2014):

> **clinch** *vb* [prob.alter. of *clench*] *vt* (1542) **1 :** CLENCH 3 ["to set or close tightly"] **2 a :** to turn over or flatten the protruding pointed end of (a driven nail); *also* : to treat (as a a screw, bolt, or rivet) in a similar way **b :** to fasten in this way **3 a :** to make final or irrefutable : SETTLE {that *clinched* the argument} **b :** to assure the winning of {scored a touchdown to *clinch* the game}

If you think of a team's season-long effort to earn a place in the league's postseason playoffs as contest to win such a spot, then the moment at which the team is assured of playing in the postseason is the moment at which it clinches the spot—and that can happen when the team wins the final game of the regular season, or when a combination of events play out in its favor (for example, it loses its final game, but so do the other three teams that were in contention for the spot, allowing it to back in to the playoffs). Indeed, if the league used a coin flip to determine which of two teams that were tied in the final regular-season standings should get a spot in the playoffs, you could say that the favorable coin flip clinched the lucky team's place in the playoffs.

It's true that a team that can get into the playoffs only if several other teams cooperate by losing can "assure the winning of" the playoff spot for itself in a rather odd way; it might be truer to say in that scenario that it can "be assured the winning of" the spot—which does stretch definition 3b slightly. But definition 3b of *clinch* isn't the only available meaning of the word. Definition 3a seems to permit the use of *clinch* to mean "settle or decide in one's favor, regardless of the means by which the settling occurs."

As for the argument that *clinch* means something like "ensures the desired outcome, regardless of what competitors do," that definition would seem to forbid using *clinch* in a situation where two teams tied for a final playoff spot are playing each other in the last game of the season—since in that case the team that wins makes the playoffs only because the other team loses. A similar notion is at work in this example from Russ Hodges, [*Baseball Complete*](https://books.google.com/books?id=wpZYAAAAYAAJ&q=%22left+home+plate+as+unprotected+as+a+cat%22&dq=%22left+home+plate+as+unprotected+as+a+cat%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=dtjTVJaMDcOtogSbuIGYAQ&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAA) (1952):

> The gifted run permitted the White Sox to down the Giants 4-2 in the 1917 World Series **clincher** and stamped Heinie as a bit of a blunderer. Truth to tell, Heinie was absolutely blameless. His mates had left home plate as unprotected as a cat at a dogshow and poor Heinie could find nobody to throw the ball to. So he set out after Collins in futile flight.

Here, the *clincher* is the deciding game of the baseball World Series. The White Sox won it and the Giants lost it, but the clinching occurred at the moment that the World Series (and the 1917 baseball season as a whole) ended.

Answer (score 0):

Definitions from the top dictionaries (in order found by google) most closely related to this topic,
clinch:
to make certain the winning of (something) http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/clinch
to settle (a matter) decisively http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/clinch?s=t
to succeed in making an agreement certain, esp. after a long period of discussion http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/american-english/clinch
*Sports* to secure (a divisional championship for instance) before the end of regular season play by having an insurmountable lead http://www.thefreedictionary.com/clinch

Do your family and friends agree with you? If so, it may be a regional connotation. However, since three of the four top resulted dictionaries do not have a "before the end of regular season" requirement, I would say that in general it is not too late to clinch something unless someone else has already clinched it.

Comment: I think the first and third definitions listed above also imply "before the end of the regular season", as they indicate that clinch means to _make certain_ the winning of something, but not to actually win it yet.  The actual contest has not yet occurred or the agreement has not been made, though it is now certain to be made or won when the time comes.  That does imply to me that the word should only be used _before_ the beginning of the playoffs.  Once the regular season ends, the playoffs have essentially begun, and there is nothing left to "clinch".  You either have a berth or you don't.

Answer (score 0):

The point is that "clinch" creates a 100% guarantee.  In that regard, "clinch" is more accurate the closer to the end of the event, i.e. the point in time the game is determined.  The only time to use the word clinch accurately would be after an event, because the results at that point are already known.

The reason clinch is used in "wild card" positions in games like football is that, even though there remain games to be played, the results are known through predetermined mathematical systems (in this case, by having unassailable victory leads).

Answer (score 0):

Clinch means Clinch. in Sports in means guaranteed of a position

Win means you won. Everything has been completed

You don't Chinch the World Series, you win it.

You clinch a divisional title or a playoff spot when prior to the end of a season, your team is mathematically guaranteed not to lose that championship or play off spot.

A team WINS a Championship.  they do not Clinch one.

Once a team WINS a championship....they can CLENCH on to that title and Trophy.

The time for clinching is prior to the final outcome when mathematically the team is guaranteed a position or Guaranteed a Title, regardless of any other outcome of all other games played.

Comment: Please [edit] your post for formatting and clarity, and take a moment to read the [FAQ] or visit the [help].  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When used in place if a narrower and clearer word like “win” is appropriate, it dilutes the meaning unique meaning of the word clinch as the only available word to describe something has been determined earlier than it is officially done. Just because a word can be used in a sense that is not helpful to understanding doesn’t mean it should be. Sport journalists should be taught not to use Clinch to conflate winning and clinching early.  Personally I find this now ubiquitous usage in sports journalism that a team has clinched a division title after the last game of the season is over OR an overall championship after only the championship game has ended.
How are now to distinguish the two situations now that “clinch” no longer implies anything other than “win.”

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).