# Is there a word for the use of period after each word of a sentence grammatically correct?

Tags: periods

I have seen statements like the one below which make deliberate use of full stops after each word of the sentence:

[image: example image]

Is there a single word for such a statement?

Comment: Since there's normally no reason to write like this, it's not clear why there would be a word for it.

Comment: @DigitalChris I've also been having that problem intermittently. But I was able to do it yesterday here: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/216757/can-a-sport-team-clinch-a-championship-in-the-last-regular-season-game#comment463263_216757

Comment: I. Never. Heard. One.

Comment: If. We. Keep. Writing. Like. This. We'll. Have. To. Invent. One.

Comment: @DigitalChris Yes: [Shatnerism](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Shatnerism) (with http://) No: [Shatnerism](www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Shatnerism)

Comment: ......Pointless

Comment: Is it just me, or does the title of this question make absolutely no sense odd with words missing?